# FullCalendar delete external events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

When I'm trying to delete an external event from my calendar, if I add say 3 external events then drag one to the bin, rather than removing just the one event it deletes all events (even the ones from the separate feeds I am doing.

Any idea why this is and how to fix it? Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //listens for drop event
    $("#calendarTrash").droppable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var answer = confirm("Delete Event?")
            if (answer) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
            }
        }
    });

    /* initialize the external events  ------------*/
    $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function () {
        // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
        // it doesn't need to have a start or end
        var eventObject = {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
        };

        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);
        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in the same circumstances,..

```
 eventDragStop: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view) {

                 if (x) {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
                      }
```

Please notice I am using event._id, x is the result of checking which div the item is dragged into returning a true or false. checks which div the event is being dropped into. I also had to change some code in fullcalendar.js
 the function eachEventElement, was causing me an issue with the above code, so I changed it too.

```
 function eachEventElement(event, exceptElement, funcName) {
    try{
        var elements = eventElementsByID[event._id],
            i, len = elements.length;
        for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
            if (!exceptElement || elements[i][0] != exceptElement[0]) {
                elements[i][funcName]();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(err)
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `event.id` in your `drop` function does not refer to the FullCalendar event. It refers to the drop event that was just triggered.

You will need to use `ui.draggable` to access your draggable - in this case the FullCalendar event.

Hope this helps! Cool concept BTW!

***Update***: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/S7Xv4/) for a proof-of-concept

Comment: thanks for looking and the fiddle website is good, but  the answer was a bit more tricky.. see below.